# SQL query to show latest order info including product images (Prestashop)

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

Using a sql query from Prestashop (1.6 & 1.7) i need to output a csv file showing the details of (x amount) my latest orders. This must include the details of each item ordered and the location of the product images for each item of each order.

I 'think' i have two parts of the sql but i dont know how to join them.

I (understand and) have this part working already

```
SELECT o.reference, c.firstname, c.lastname, a.lastname, a.firstname, a.address1, a.address2, a.postcode, a.city, a.phone, a.phone_mobile, o.id_order
FROM ps_orders o
LEFT JOIN ps_customer c on (c.id_customer = o.id_customer)
LEFT JOIN ps_address a on (a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery)
OUTER JOIN  (SELECT  *  from ps_order_detail where id_order = o.id_order limit 1) od1 on (o.id_order = o.id_order)

order by id_order desc limit 5
```

and this - that i borrowed on stack exchange

```
select
p.`id_product`
,pl.`name`
,concat('http:/mydomain.com/',cl.`link_rewrite`,'/',pl.`link_rewrite`,'-',p.`id_product`,'.html') as "ProductURL"
,case
    when length(im.`id_image`)=6 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(insert(insert(insert(insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),4,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),8,0,'/'),10,0,'/'),'/',im.`id_image`,'.jpg')
    when length(im.`id_image`)=5 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(insert(insert(insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),4,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),8,0,'/'),'/',im.`id_image`,'.jpg')
    when length(im.`id_image`)=4 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(insert(insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),4,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),'/',im.`id_image`,'.jpg')
    when length(im.`id_image`)=3 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),4,0,'/'),'/',im.`id_image`,'.jpg')
    when length(im.`id_image`)=2 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),'/',im.`id_image`,'.jpg')
    when length(im.`id_image`)=1 then
     concat('http:/mydomain.com/img/p/',insert(im.`id_image`,2,0,'/'),im.`id_image`,'.jpg')  

    else ''
    end as "ImgURL_1"
FROM `ps_product` p
join `ps_product_lang` pl on pl.`id_product`= p.`id_product`
join `ps_category_lang` cl on cl.`id_category`= p.`id_category_default`
join `ps_image` im on im.`id_product`= p.`id_product`
where pl.`id_lang`=1 and cl.`id_lang`=1 and im.`cover`=1 and p.`active`=1
```

[image]

Basically i need all the information you get on a normal Prestashop delivery slip i.e customer name, Address, Product name etc AND product image location. This will then be pulled into Adobe Indesign for a customised delivery slip. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution (includes some additional info about the customers order)

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
 SELECT 
       o.reference          AS order_reference,
       c.firstname          AS customer_first_name,
       c.lastname,
       a.lastname,
       a.firstname,
       a.address1,
       a.address2,
       a.postcode,
       a.city,
       a.phone,
       a.phone_mobile,
       o.id_order,
       od1.product_id       AS Product1ID,
       prod1.name           AS Product1,
       prod1.url_image      AS Product1Image,
       prod1.ProductURL     AS Product1URL,
       od1.product_quantity AS Product1Quantity,
       od2.product_id       AS Product2ID,
       prod2.name           AS Product2,
       prod2.url_image      AS Product2Image,
       prod2.ProductURL     AS Product2URL,
       od2.product_quantity AS Product2Quantity,
       od3.product_id       AS Product3ID,
       prod3.name           AS Product3,
       prod3.url_image      AS Product3Image,
       prod3.ProductURL     AS Product3URL,
       od3.product_quantity AS Product3Quantity,
       od4.product_id       AS Product4ID,
       prod4.name           AS Product4,
       prod4.url_image      AS Product4Image,
       prod4.ProductURL     AS Product4URL,
       od4.product_quantity AS Product4Quantity,
       od5.product_id       AS Product5ID,
       prod5.name           AS Product5,
       prod5.url_image      AS Product5Image,
       prod5.ProductURL     AS Product5URL,
       od5.product_quantity AS Product5Quantity,
       od6.product_id       AS Product6ID,
       prod6.name           AS Product6,
       prod6.url_image      AS Product6Image,
       prod6.ProductURL     AS Product6URL,
       od6.product_quantity AS Product6Quantity,
       o.payment,
       o.invoice_date
       FROM   ps_orders o
       LEFT JOIN ps_customer c
              ON ( c.id_customer = o.id_customer )
       LEFT JOIN ps_address a
              ON ( a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery )
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od1
              ON od1.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  1)
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od2
              ON od2.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  1, 1)
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od3
              ON od3.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  2, 1)
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od4
              ON od4.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  3, 1)
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od5
              ON od5.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  4, 1)
       LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od6
              ON od6.id_order_detail = (SELECT d.id_order_detail
                                        FROM   ps_order_detail AS d
                                        WHERE  o.id_order = d.id_order
                                        ORDER  BY d.id_order_detail
                                        LIMIT  5, 1)

       LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
                         pl.name              AS 'Name',
        Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
       Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
       Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
              IF
       (
              Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product


    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod1
ON od1.product_id = prod1.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
           pl.name              AS 'Name',
           Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
           Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
           Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
IF (
Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod2
ON od2.product_id = prod2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
           pl.name              AS 'Name',
           Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
           Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
           Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
IF (
Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod3
ON od3.product_id = prod3.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
           pl.name              AS 'Name',
           Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
           Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
           Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
IF (
Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod4
ON od4.product_id = prod4.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
           pl.name              AS 'Name',
           Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
           Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
           Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
IF (
Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod5
ON od5.product_id = prod5.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.id_product         AS 'ID',
           pl.name              AS 'Name',
          Concat('{ImagePath}', pl.`link_rewrite`, '.jpg') AS "ProductURL",
           Concat('https://your_url.com/img/p/',
           Mid(im.id_image, 1, 1), '/',
IF (
Length(im.id_image) > 1, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 2, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(
Length(im.id_image) > 2, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 3, 1), '/'), ''), IF
(Length(im.id_image) > 3,
Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF (Length(im.id_image) > 4, Concat(Mid(im.id_image, 5, 1), '/'), ''),
im.id_image, '.jpg') AS url_image
    FROM   ps_product p
           INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl
                   ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
           LEFT JOIN ps_image im
                  ON p.id_product = im.id_product
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND p.active = 1) prod6
ON od6.product_id = prod6.id
GROUP  BY o.id_order
ORDER  BY o.id_order DESC
LIMIT  10
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works with PrestaShop 1.6/1.7, will generate a CSV file with all you need, including an image:**

```
<?php

include('config/config.inc.php');
include('init.php');

$context = Context::getContext();
$id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT', (int)$context->shop->id);

$order_details = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
SELECT o.reference, c.firstname, c.lastname, a.lastname, a.firstname, a.address1, a.address2, a.postcode, s.name state, a.city, a.phone, a.phone_mobile, o.id_order,
od.product_id, od.product_name, od.product_quantity, od.product_reference, i.id_image, pl.link_rewrite
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer c on (c.id_customer = o.id_customer)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'address a on (a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'state s on (a.id_state = s.id_state)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od ON (od.id_order = o.id_order)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'image i ON (i.id_product = od.product_id)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = od.product_id)
WHERE o.valid = 1 AND i.cover = 1 AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.' AND pl.id_shop = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
ORDER BY o.id_order DESC
LIMIT 5');

foreach ($order_details as &$od)
    $od['product_image'] = $context->link->getImageLink($od['link_rewrite'], $od['id_image'], 'home_default');

if (count($order_details))
{
    /* CSV Separator */
    $csv_sep = ',';
    $csv_delim = '"';

    /* CSV Header */
    $csv = '';
    foreach ($order_details[0] as $k => $val)
        $csv .= $k.$csv_sep;
    $csv = rtrim($csv, $csv_sep)."\n";

    /* Ordered products */
    foreach ($order_details as $line)
    {
        foreach ($line as $column)
            $csv .= $csv_delim.$column.$csv_delim.$csv_sep;
        $csv = rtrim($csv, $csv_sep)."\n";
    }

    /* Comment the two lines below if you'd just like to display instead of forcing download */
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="orders-'.date('YmdHis').'.csv"');
    echo $csv;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: CSV preview]

**What I did:**

- Added `_DB_PREFIX_`, making sure it will work on other PrestaShop shops that might have a database table prefix different from `ps_`
- Added `o.valid = 1` to include only paid and valid orders
- Added a `JOIN` on the `image` table to select the product cover picture
- Added the state name (e.g. Florida, California, etc.)
- Added the product name, ID, reference and quantities ordered
- Retrieved the product image using built-in PrestaShop methods
- Generated the CSV file dynamically

I hope this helps!